# Spring: Not able to load bean reference file

Tags: java, spring

My web.xml looks like this:
        `<context-param>
        <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
        <param-value>app.context</param-value>
    </context-param>`

there is a file with the name `beanRefContext.xml` at `bin/target/projectName/WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Content of beanRefContext is standard. It lists other configuration files under the bean name `app.context`.

```
    <bean id="app.context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
     <constructor-arg>
        <list>
         <value></value>
         <value></value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

**Error**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [app.context], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'app.context' is defined
10:49:54,686 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:402) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: `beanRefContext.xml` is not standard file :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. What should I do then?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a parentContextKey in a normal webapp? There is already a hierarchy of contexts in the standard Spring MVC webapp.

Comment: Are you testing this from within Eclipse? Try packaging the app in a .war and deploy to a server.

Comment: Post the complete `web.xml` and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Would not be able to post complete `web.xml`. Yes Tried packaging it in a war and deploying it directly to the server.

Comment: Then I don't know. I tested your scenario and works for me.